# Chrome (44 version) not working with self signed certificate

Tags: google-chrome, self-signed, poodle-attack, sslv3

I am using self signed certificate for localhost in my web application. Recently i updated apache to 2.2.29 and openssl to 1.0.1m as recommended and disabled sslv3 and v2 for security.

After this everytime accessing my application(every every page inside my app) over chrome(version 44 on windws) shows message "Your connection is not private". Somehow it does not remember certificate or is denying.

And this does not happen on any other browser(FF, IE) even Chrome(version 33).

I've tried using 1024bit RSA certificate and 2048bit RSA certifictae. My apache ssl config options are

```
SSLProtocol +ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!MD5:!LOW:!EXP:!RC4+RSA:!SSLv2:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
```

Is there some issue with chrome over tls or ciphersuite i am using should be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to know the reason behind it.

Seems chrome confirmed this issue from their end for version 44.  It is already reported 2 weeks ago and fixed by chrome in 45 version.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513903
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473390